# How to scrape responsive page with a scroll on intern div with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape this page https://sports.sportingbet.com/pt-br/sports/futebol-4/hoje
get the teams and the odds, and put then in a dataframe

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
river.get('https://sports.sportingbet.com/pt-br/sports/futebol-4/hoje')
sleep(5)
teams = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="grid-event-wrapper image ng-star-inserted"]')
home, visitor = [], []
for i in range(len(teams)):
    times = teams[i].text
    separete_times = times.split('\n')
    if len(separete_times) >= 2:
        home_team = separete_times[0]
        visitor_team = separete_times[1]
        home.append(home_team)
        visitor.append(visitor_team)

odds = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="grid-option-group grid-group ng-star-inserted"]')
home_win, draw, visitor_win = [], [], []
for i in range(len(odds)):
    all_odds = odds[i].text
    separete_odds = all_odds.split('\n')
    if len(separete_odds) >= 3:
        home_team_wind = separete_odds[0]
        draw_result = separete_odds[1]
        visitor_team_win = separete_odds[2]
        home_win.append(home_team_wind)
        draw.append(draw_result)
    visitor_win.append(visitor_team_win)
```

This code works fine, but gets just 50 matchs, for get all I need to scroll down the page to load new games, I try diferent ways, but doesn't work

This are my attempts

```
altura_total = driver.execute_script('return document.getElementById("main-view").offsetHeight;')
script_scroll = f'document.getElementById("main-view").scrollTop = 1000;'

column_wrapper = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="column column-center ng-scrollbar ng-star-inserted"]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);', column_wrapper)    
    column_center_div = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'footer-top-links')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight;', column_center_div)
    column_center_div = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'column.column-center')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight;', column_center_div)
    driver.execute_script('scrollBy(0, 250)')
```